# Vim Ex mode loads when opening terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, vim, terminal

I know little about Vim in terminal(Mac) and the other day I was working copy and pasting text and i think I accidently did it when in terminal. Now whenever I open terminal it instantly loads on Vim Ex mode. I know how to quit Ex mode once in terminal but is there any way i can get rid of Vim loading when I open Terminal?

Thanks

Edit: To explain further to what i mean when I open terminal.app from Utilities I get the following [image: Terminal opening with vim]

and the only way I get back to the command prompt is by typing quit every time I open terminal and i cant understand why the Vim process is running in the first place.

I was just outside the terminal in a document copy and pasting text then accidentally did a command v to paste within terminal which resulted in this happening.

Comment: I am fluent in Vim and know few pieces of OS X Terminal, but I have no clue what you are talking about. That might also be the reason nobody replied as of yet. Care to explain in details what is happening, how do you launch terminal, what terminal app you use, what commands did you run, why do you think you have Vim running when launch terminal? What is the terminal launching command... Simply, give us more information if you need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you've accidentally updated one of your shell startup scripts so it launches vim.

If your default shell is csh or tcsh, take a look at `.cshrc`, `.tcshrc`, and `.login` in your home directory, and look for a command like `vi -e` or `vim -e`.

If your default shell is bash, check `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

It may be easier to figure out which file you messed up by checking which file in your home directory was modified most recently:

```
% ls -altr $HOME | tail
```

- `-a` lists all files, including files whose names start with `.`.
- `-l` gives you a long listing, showing timestamps.
- `-t` sorts by modification time.
- `-r` reverses the order, so newer files are shown last

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue with my MacBook Air M1 after making changes to the **.zshrc** file.

To troubleshoot, I initially tried to locate the problematic line, but if you are unable to find it, you can make a backup of the entire text within the .zshrc file and then proceed to delete all of its contents. This helps determine if the problem is related to the shell startup scripts. If the issue persists, you can gradually re-add the configuration lines to identify the specific cause.