# .bash_profile# file is opening in vim when i am opening Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, default, macos-high-sierra

Whenever I am opening Terminal, ~/.bash_profile# file is opening in VIM.

1. When I clicked 2+ctrl+g i am getting below file details
   buf 1: "~/.bash_profile#" line 1 of 6 --16%-- col 1 (1 of 8)
2. Tried from [Vim Ex mode loads when opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844238/vim-ex-mode-loads-when-opening-terminal) where I am getting

Roys-Air:Desktop username$ ls -altr $HOME | tail
-rw-------   1 username  staff  12288 Jul 10 01:26 .swo
-rw-r--r--   1 username  staff  12288 Jul 10 01:27 .bash_profile#.swp
-rw-r--r--   1 username  staff      0 Jul 10 01:29 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x   4 username  staff    128 Jul 10 01:38 private
-rw-r--r--@  1 username  staff  14340 Jul 10 01:38 .DS_Store
-rw-------   1 username  staff   9986 Jul 10 01:40 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 username  staff      5 Jul 10 01:40 .bash_profile#
-rw-------   1 username  staff   8402 Jul 10 01:40 .viminfo
drwxr-xr-x+ 52 username  staff   1664 Jul 10 01:40 .
drwx------  81 username  staff   2592 Jul 10 01:40 .bash_sessions

I am expecting terminal should open like Roys-Air:~ UserName$

.bash_profile is containing below content

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/mongodb
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin
##
# Your previous /Users/rajnikantroy/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/rajnikantroy/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2018-12-07_at_02:06:08
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2018-12-07_at_02:06:08: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
vim .bash_profile# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export ANT_HOME=/Users/rajnikantroy/Documents/ant/apache-ant-1.10.6/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Comment: What is in .bash_profile?

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson, I have added .bash_profile content in post.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your bash profile and correct the line starting with `vim .bash_profile`. In vim:

```
:/vim .bash_profile/normal! 0dt#
```